# Recommended reading to understand American economic history

Tags: history, usa

In [India Unbound](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/296201.India_Unbound), the author goes over India's economic history, right from independence to present day. I am interested in a similar reading for the United States, specifically conditions in the 20th century.

Any decent suggestions which comes close? I found [10 books](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2014/03/08/10-great-books-on-american-economic-history.aspx) but any one in particular which stands out and is a must read?

Currently this one stands out to me, other suggestions welcome. [The Rise and Fall of American Growth: The U.S. Standard of Living since the Civil War](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691147728)

Comment: The book you mentioned is complete BS. [Refer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpCk4Vl_8P8&t=4s&ab_channel=BlackFlagIndia)

Answer (score 1):

Found this to have more breadth on the overall US economy: [The Rise and Fall of American Growth: The U.S. Standard of Living since the Civil War](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691147728)

Answer (score 0):

The Ascent of Money, This Time it's Different, and Other People's Money. All great reads.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Economics.SE. Do you mind expanding a bit your answer? Maybe write about the published year, the author. How do those books cover the history of Economics in the USA (which years are covered, etc.).